# How copy value of input text to other inputs texts

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How copy value of input text to other Input texts elements in AngularJS 1.X

But each input has have his own property in controller

I've tried so far

```
 <div class="paramWrap"> // copy from here
    <label for="accoubntDis">Account Discount</label>
        <input id="accoubntDis" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="accoubntDis">
 </div>

 <pre>{{accoubntDis}}</pre> // only this displayed

    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="paramWrap">
        <label for="365Dis">O365 Exchange Unlicensed Discount</label>
        <input id="365Dis" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{accoubntDis}}" ng-model="accoubntDis12">
    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="paramWrap">
        <label for="gSuiteO365">G Suite / O365 Exchange Paused/Archived</label>
        <input id="gSuiteO365" type="text" class="form-control" value={{accoubntDis}} ng-model="gSuiteO365">
    </div>
```

What I see actually that only the   `<pre>{{accoubntDis}}</pre>` is displayed

why `value/ng-value={{accoubntDis}}/"accoubntDis"` not worked in `<input ....` ??

[image]

[image]

Do I need to use any JS functions on controller side for this ?

Comment: Images of code are hard to read and makes it difficult to reproduce a problem or write an answer.

Comment: Don't mix `ng-model` with `ng-value`. Use `ng-model` for two-way binding; `ng-value` for one-way binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **simplest** and **best** approach would be to use **ng-change** instead of ng-value.

HTML code:

```
<input type = "text" ng-model = "first" ng-change = "changeSecond()"/>
<input type = "text" ng-model = "second"/>
```

Angular: js corresponding code

```
$scope.changeSecond = function() {
    $scope.second = $scope.first;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with "ng-value", its working in angular 1.5 and above. 
If you angular is below 1.5 you can go for below approach.

- So better you write a function call on change of input field1, and in
  that function assign the value of field1 to field2. Consider the below sample example.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data" ng-change="updateField()">
<input type="text" ng-model="meta">
```

**JS:**

```
  $scope.data;
  $scope.meta;
  $scope.updateField= function(){
      $scope.meta=$scope.data;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In input doesn't need the {{}}, just go with **value="accoubntDis"** will do.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div class="paramWrap"> // copy from here
    <label for="accoubntDis">Account Discount</label>
    <input id="accoubntDis" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="accoubntDis" ng-change="calculate()">
</div>

 <pre>{{accoubntDis}}</pre> // only this displayed

    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="paramWrap">
        <label for="365Dis">O365 Exchange Unlicensed Discount</label>
        <input id="365Dis" type="text" class="form-control" ng-value="accoubntDis2">
    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="paramWrap">
        <label for="gSuiteO365">G Suite / O365 Exchange Paused/Archived</label>
        <input id="gSuiteO365" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="accoubntDis3">
</div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.accoubntDis = "100";
  $scope.accoubntDis2 = $scope.accoubntDis * 2;
  $scope.accoubntDis3 = $scope.accoubntDis / 2;

  $scope.calculate = function(){
  $scope.accoubntDis2 = $scope.accoubntDis * 2;
  $scope.accoubntDis3 = $scope.accoubntDis / 2;
}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might be what u want. Get data bind with ng-model and pass to other view? <input id="365Dis" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="accoubntDis">

Comment: Add pictures...I need to display a text of Main Input to others....but each can have his data or discount in my case

Comment: Can do <input id="gSuiteO365" type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="accoubntDis2 "> You can access the field with id for other purpose after this. By bind another ng-model variable in the controller u do your calculation. For example: accoubntDis2 = accoubntDis *2; Bind accoubntDis2 instead of accoubntDis

Comment: @ Lucas , can you post a whole suggested solution ?

Comment: can have a try again, this will give u idea how the thing work

Comment: Yes , it Almost works :) , have a little bug when you edit the 2nd ,3rd input text and than back to original to main ...Copy Not working ...

Comment: Are you mean u going to change accoubntDis2 /accoubntDis3 value? in this case you need add extra ng-change to preform the calculation needed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-value` directive.

```html
<input ng-value="accoubntDis" />
```

Refer to this [API doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue).

---

**BTW**, as you're using `ng-model`, `value` will be overridden so that it seems to be not working.

```html
<input ng-model="accoubntDis" />
```

Comment: binding by `{{}}` is not correct for `input` tag. check the updated answer.

Comment: From the link of your answer : "...when that element does not use ngModel."

Comment: ng-model="accoubntDis" not working... Added pictures to my questions

Comment: remove `ng-value` attribute and only use `ng-model` for `input[type=text]` element.

Comment: @Ali D. , so each input text element will have the same ng-model property ? I need to have individual property in the server per input text

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-value directive.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


<div class="paramWrap"> 
    <label for="accoubntDis">Account Discount</label>
        <input id="accoubntDis" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="accoubntDis">
 </div>

 <pre>{{accoubntDis}}</pre> 

    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="paramWrap">
        <label for="365Dis">O365 Exchange Unlicensed Discount</label>
        <input id="365Dis" type="text" class="form-control" ng-value="accoubntDis" ng-model="accoubntDis12">
    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="paramWrap">
        <label for="gSuiteO365">G Suite / O365 Exchange Paused/Archived</label>
        <input id="gSuiteO365" type="text" class="form-control" value={{accoubntDis}} ng-model="gSuiteO365">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.accountDis = "Hello World!";
    $scope.accoubntDis=123;
});
</script>

<p>This example shows how to use AngularJS expressions to set the value of an input field.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't mix `ng-model` with `ng-value`. Use `ng-model` for two-way binding; `ng-value` for one-way binding.